# Average Opening Day based on MM/DD

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to figure out how to get the "Average day we open" what function can do this?

On my database I have season info by season via rows and in one column I have the last 10 years of opening dates ( Dec 8, Dec 5, Nov 23 etc)
Is there a way to use a formula to return the average day we open our doors? "Avg Opening Day (MM.DD)" over the last 10 years?

Comment: I agree with @G-Man .. this should be a non-issue if the dates are stored as dates.

Comment: Guys, I think he wants to ignore the year. So it's not a simple average of the date serials.  Matt, if I'm right about your task, you need to first get the day of the year for each date.Then average those numbers and convert back to a date.  I'll take a crack at this tomorrow, or if that's enough information, go for it. :-)

Comment: @Matt ,, just provide me the Sample Data and the Criteria, I can do it by using the Regression Command to Forecast the Average Opening Day or Best Date to Kick off.

Comment: @Bandersnatch - That is correct, we want to ignore the Year.  Thank you!

Comment: Date are 12/8, 12/5, 11/25, 11/26, 12/8, 12/14, 11/23, 11/27, 11/20, 12/2

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are actual dates in cells `B2:B11` we could convert them all to a specific year (1900) and then average, so......

`=TEXT(AVERAGE(DATE(0,MONTH(B2:B11),DAY(B2:B11)))+0.5,"m/d")`

Confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

For dates excel will effectively round down so the `+0.5` ensures that we get the nearest date

[image]

If you want you can add an `INDEX` function to avoid "array entry"

`=TEXT(AVERAGE(INDEX(DATE(0,MONTH(B2:B11),DAY(B2:B11)),0))+0.5,"m/d")`

Finally - this is one case where it's easier if the dates are text values. If the values are just `"12/8"`, `"12/5"` etc. then when we "co-erce" those with some mathematical operation like `+0` Excel will automatically assume they are dates in the current year, so this array formula should work

`=TEXT(AVERAGE(B2:B11+0)+0.5,"m/d")`

Note: For actual dates if you have an **odd** number of dates in **consecutive** years then just a simple average would give you something close to the correct result (month and day wise), although it might be slightly skewed by leap years

Comment: Very nice, @barry.

Comment: THANKS EVERYONE! I think I have what I need! Much appreciated!!